# Using Policy Iteration on an automaton

Tags: machine-learning, markov-process

I've read many explanation on how do to policy iteration, but I can't find an example, so I'm stuck right now trying to figure out to Policy Iteration.

[image]

The numbers next to each state show the reward received for *arriving* in that state. For example, if the agent started in $S_0$ and took the $Blue$ action, and ended up in state $S_1$, the immediate reward would be $-5$.

The discount value is 0.1, and the initial policy is $\pi(S_0)=Blue$ and $\pi(S_1)=Red$

$S_2 $ state is the terminal state - game over. The two possible actions are Blue and Red as can be seen on the image.

I just need something to help me start, because no explanation really made me understand how do I start the policy iteration till convergence.

Comment: OK, so the trouble is that any answer here will necessarily be an *explanation*. Could you maybe link an explanation that you are struggling with, and show where it is that you lose understanding? Also, what form is your policy iteration taking? A manual work-through of the process, or some code?

Comment: Another question. In your diagram, are the rewards for arriving in, or leaving the state that you have labelled? E.g. does the label $S_0, -2$ mean that the agent receives a -2 reward for *arriving* in $S_0$ or for leaving it? Both are valid MDPs, but the value functions will be different.

Comment: Its the reward for Arriving. For your first question, its a manual work through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Policy Iteration is essentially a two step process:

1. Evaluate the current policy by calculating $v(s)$ for every non-terminal state.

   - Internally this requires multiple loops over all the states until the value calculations are accurate enough
2. Improve the policy by choosing the best action $\pi(s)$ for every non-terminal state

The overall process terminates when it is not possible to improve the policy in the second part. When that happens, then - from the Bellman equations for the optimal value function - the value function and policy must be optimal.

In detail for your example, it might work like this:

- Initialise our value function for $[S_0, S_1, S_2]$ as $[0,0,0]$ - note that by definition for the terminal state $v(S_2)=0$ so we never need to recalculate that (this is also consistent with the diagram, which shows the "absorbing" actions) so we *could* actually calculate it if we want, but it's a waste of time.
- Choose a value for accuracy limit $\theta$. To avoid going on forever in the example, let's pick a high value, say $0.01$. However, if this was computer code, I might set it lower e.g. $10^{-6}$
- Set our discount factor, $\gamma = 0.1$. Note this is quite low, heavily emphasising immediate rewards over longer-term ones.
- Set our current policy $\pi = [B, R]$. We're ready to start.
- First we have to do policy evaluation, which is multiple passes through all states, updating $v(s) = \sum_{s',r} p(s',r|s,\pi(s))(r + \gamma v(s'))$. There are other ways of writing this formula, all basically equivalent, the one here is from Sutton & Barto 2nd edition. We also can choose between a "pure" iteration calculating $v_{k+1}(s)$ from $v_{k}(s)$, but I will do the update in place to the same $v$ array, because that is easier and usually faster too.

  - Note each sum here is over the two possible $(s', r)$ results from each action.
  - Pass 1 in detail, iterating though states $[S_0, S_1]$:

    - Set max delta ($\Delta = 0$) to track our accuracy
    - $v(S_0) = \sum_{s',r} p(s',r|S_0,B)(r + \gamma v(s')) = 0.5(-5 + 0.1 v(S_1)) + 0.5 (-2 + 0.1 v(S_0)) = -3.5$
    - This sets max delta to 3.5
    - $v(S_1) = \sum_{s',r} p(s',r|S_1,R)(r + \gamma v(s')) = 0.6(-5 + 0.1 v(S_1)) + 0.4 (0 + 0.1 v(S_2)) = -3$
    - Max delta is still 3.5
    - The $v$ table is now $[-3.5, -3, 0]$
  - Pass 2, because $\Delta \gt 0.01$:

    - Reset $\Delta = 0$
    - $v(S_0) = 0.5(-5 + 0.1 v(S_1)) + 0.5 (-2 + 0.1 v(S_0)) = -3.825$
    - $\Delta = 0.325$
    - $v(S_1) = 0.6(-5 + 0.1 v(S_1)) + 0.4 (0 + 0.1 v(S_2)) = -3.180$
    - $\Delta = 0.325 \gt 0.01$
    - The $v$ table is now $[-3.825, -3.180, 0]$
  - Pass 3, $v = [-3.850, -3.191, 0]$
  - Pass 4, $v = [-3.852, -3.191, 0]$, this is small enough change that we'll say evaluation has converged.
- Now we need to check whether the policy should be changed. For each non-terminal state we need to work through all possible actions and find the action with the highest expected return, $\pi(s) = \text{argmax}_a \sum_{s',r} p(s',r|s,a)(r + \gamma v(s'))$

  - For $S_0$:

    - Action B scores $0.5(-5 + 0.1 v(S_1)) + 0.5 (-2 + 0.1 v(S_0)) = -3.852$ (technically, we already know that because it is the current policy's action)
    - Action R scores $0.9(-2 + 0.1 v(S_0)) + 0.1 (0 + 0.1 v(S_2)) = -2.147$
    - R is the best action here, so change $\pi(S_0) = R$
  - For $S_1$:

    - Action B scores $0.8(-2 + 0.1 v(S_0)) + 0.2 (-5 + 0.1 v(S_1)) = -2.971$
    - Action R scores -3.191
    - B is the best action here, so change $\pi(S_1) = B$
  - Our policy has changed, so we go around both major stages again, starting with policy evaluation and the current $v = [-3.852, -3.191, 0]$, using the new policy $[R, B]$

I leave it up to you to do the second pass through evaluation and improvement. I suspect it will show that the new policy is optimal, and the policy will remain $[R, B]$ (although $[R,R]$ seems possible without doing the calculation). If the policy stays the same on a complete pass through evaluation and improvement, then you are done.